# How to find the simplest human-readable float string which would yield the same bytes when converted back to float?

Tags: serialization, floating-point, precision, human-readable

For most numbers, we know there will be some precision error with any floating point value. For a 32-bit float, that works out the be roughly 6 significant digits which will be accurate before you can expect to start seeing incorrect values.

I'm trying to store a human-readable value which can be read in and recreate a bit-accurate recreation of the serialized value.

For example, the value `555.5555` is stored as `555.55548095703125`; but when I serialize `555.55548095703125`, I could theoretically serialize it as anything in the range `(555.5554504395, 555.555511475)` (exclusive) and still get the same byte pattern. (Actually, probably that's not the exact range, I just don't know that there's value in calculating it more accurately at the moment.)

What I'd like is to find the most human-readable string representation for the value -- which I imagine would be the fewest digits -- which will be deserialized as the same IEEE float.

Comment: FYI, Java and JavaScript do this in their default formatting for `float` and `double`, so printing a `float` or `double` or converting one to a string in these languages accomplishes the goal, except for some decorative aspects (the shortest string for .3 would be “.3”, but they produce “0.3”).

Comment: I'd second Python repr() does the same: finds a shortest decimal representation that is converted to the same value. There would be more standard libraries with the same facility. So you can simply pick and analyze a one closest to you.

Comment: In my case (and I probably should have specified this) I'm using C++, so neither JavaScript nor Python would be practical. Though I am now curious what process both languages use to come up with their string representations -- whether it's essentially `snprintf(val, "%1.6g")` or something else designed to produce a more elegant result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly a problem which was initially solved in 1990 with an algorithm the creators called "Dragon": https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=93559

There is a more modern technique from last year which is notably faster called "Ryu" (Japanese for "dragon"): https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3192369

The GitHub for the library is here: https://github.com/ulfjack/ryu

According to their readme:

> Ryu generates the shortest decimal representation of a floating point
>   number that maintains round-trip safety. That is, a correct parser can
>   recover the exact original number. For example, consider the binary
>   64-bit floating point number 00111110100110011001100110011010. The
>   stored value is exactly 0.300000011920928955078125. However, this
>   floating point number is also the closest number to the decimal number
>   0.3, so that is what Ryu outputs.